# How to configure `*.graphql` imports for TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, graphql

I want to publish a package that contains a type declaration for `*.graphql` "modules", and have projects consume the package so that they can write `import` statements for queries written in other files. Is this possible?

Here's what I have so far.

I have the following type, in a file named `graphql.d.ts`.

```js
declare module '*.graphql' {
  import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql';
  const Schema: DocumentNode;

  export default defaultDocument;
}
```

And my `package.json` looks like this.

```json
{
  "name": "@my-private-scope/type-graphql-imports",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "types": "graphql.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "graphql.d.ts"
  ],
  "peerDependencies": {
    "graphql": ">=14.0.0"
  }
}
```

But after publishing this package and importing it into a different project, I have the following errors.

`error TS2307: Cannot find module './query.graphql' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Is there a way to configure the project so that these types are visible to the compiler?

Comment: Could you please include your consumer project's tsconfig file/s as well any triple slash directives used in the consumer project? The first thing that came to mind is that you might not be including the library types (or including correctly) in your tsconfig but the issue might be quite deeper. A minimal reproducible example would be nice, since many factors can cause this behavior.

Comment: I was always amazed how people are opening bounties on questions and then just not showing up for the follow-ups. This happens surprisingly often!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, but there are two questions/answers, i.e. *two things you are missing*

- **A**) on *how to generate/modularize the `graphql queries`*
- & **B**) how to `fix` those for the typescript `compiler errors` your are having.

*Lets begin, please consider the answers and their sub options*...

---

> ## Answer A:
>
> > #### Resuse/Modularize-- to generate/create the typescripts modules/components for your `GraphQl` Queries, *you can use 3 options*, i.e.
>
> - **1**) the built in [GraphQl Generator](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-graphql-files-modules),
> - **2**) A simpler roll your own with config webpack/loader
> - **3**) using the [GraphQl Fragments Ref.](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments), and then using the fragments you can componentize them like so [GraphQl Fragments Sample](https://www.voorhoede.nl/en/blog/componentize-data-with-graphql-fragments/)

#### Option 1: there is a built in generator you can use to simplify things in combination with webpack.

- A. Look here https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-graphql-files-modules for their ref. samples below.. you can setup something like this generator and then it will generate the code klisted in B

---

```
generates: src/api/user-service/queries.d.ts
 documents: src/api/user-service/queries.graphql
 plugins:
   - typescript-graphql-files-modules
 config:
   # resulting module definition path glob: "*\/api/user-service/queries.graphql"
   modulePathPrefix: "/api/user-service/"
```

- B, in a nutshell.. it allows you to have a query named MyQuery in `my-query.graphql` file, this template will generate the following code:

---

```
declare module '*/my-query.graphql' {
  import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql';
  const MyQuery: DocumentNode;

  export { MyQuery };

  export default defaultDocument;
}
Accordingly, you can import the generated types and use it in your code:

import myQuery from './my-query.graphql';

// OR

import { myQuery } from './my-query.graphql';
```

#### Option 2 Simpler e.g.

---

Simple form, I recommend using `webpack loader` to feed your [webpack config apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/recipes/webpack/)

```typescript
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'graphql-tag/loader'
  }
]
```

Avoid double quotes and specicl characters in your queries.graphql

```typescript
query GetAllRoles($value: String) {
 Role(filter: { role: $value }) {
    role
 }
}
```

Now, you can reuse it with query values

```typescript
import GetAllRoles from './queries.graphql'
 .....
 this.apollo.query({
  query: GetAllRoles,
  variables: {
    value: GetAllRoles, 
  }
})
  .subscribe(....)
```

---

Some more examples and details for the module creation and [resolvers here](https://blog.logrocket.com/graphql-modules-tutorial-how-to-modularize-graphql-schema/) to help you

---

> ## Answer B:
>
> > #### to *fix* the `Typescript compiler errors` your are facing

First, the `typescript definitions`/types for `graphql` are `missing`, and you have to **manually configure/add/extend the Typescript definition**.

```
// in your webpack.d.ts
declare module "*.gql" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}

declare module "*.graphql" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

Second, *if thats doesn't fix it*, then also please try adding this in `tsconfig.json`, to prevent typescript compiler from applying module types to imported javascript.

```
// in your tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  "allowJs": true,
  "checkJs": false,
    ...
  }
}
```